# Missing disk IO stats at gnome-system-monitor

Tags: disk, monitoring, system-monitor, io

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, just plain/default ext4 installation (updated/upgraded). I can see stats from command line with `iostat`. Like on [gnome-system-monitor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouwgm.png): system monitor only displays disk IO stats for own process, other have `N/A`.

How can I fix it (configure maybe) to display stats for other processes as well?